# Combobox scrolling issue in ZK Framework

Tags: combobox

When i click on combo box then options are opening below this combo box

when i am scrolling the window with the help of mouse scroller then window is scrolling down but combo box option is present at the same place. Below of this combo box option value is showing below the middle name

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comp.addEventListener(Events.ON_MOUSE_OUT, new EventListener() {
             public void onEvent(Event event) {

```
             for(int i=0;i<comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().size();i++) {
                    //for(int j=0;j<comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().size();j++) {
                        if(comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren()!=null)
                        for(int k=0;k<comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().size();k++) {
                            if(comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().size()>0 && comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().size()==1 && comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().size()>0 && comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().get(0) instanceof Combobox) {

                                Combobox combobox=(Combobox) comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().get(0);
                                         if(combobox!=null) {

                                             combobox.close();
                                         }

                                    }
                            else if(comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().size()>0 && comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().size()>1 && comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().size()>0 && comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().get(1) instanceof Combobox) {

                                Combobox combobox=(Combobox) comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().get(1);
                                 if(combobox!=null) {

                                     combobox.close();
                                 }

                                    }

                            else if(comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().size()>0 && comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().size()>1 && comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().size()>0 && comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().get(0) instanceof Datebox) {

                                Datebox datebox=(Datebox) comp.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getChildren().get(0);
                                 if(datebox!=null) {

                                     datebox.close();
                                 }

                                    }


                        //}
                    }
                }

         }
     });


}
```